# Angular6: Creating dynamic list of radiobutton with Ids

Tags: angular

I need to create a dynamic list of radio buttons from json array. I am able to do that but the requirement is to assign a dynamic Id to each of them. My JSON data looks like:

```js
this.employees = [{
      employeeId: 1,
      employeeName: 'Mark Hunt',
      imageURL: '',
      rating: 0,
      group: 'Training'
    }, {
        employeeId: 2,
        employeeName: 'Dave Piana',
        imageURL: '',
        rating: 0,
        group: 'Technical'
      }];
```

The output I expect is:

```html
<div class="row">
  <fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id='radio_1_5' name="Training" value="5" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio_1_4" name="Training" value="4" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio_1_3" name="Training" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio_1_2" name="Training" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio_1_1" name="Training" value="1" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id='radio_2_5' name="Technical" value="5" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio_2_4" name="Technical" value="4" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio_2_3" name="Technical" value="3" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio_2_2" name="Technical" value="2" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio_2_1" name="Technical" value="1" />
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

The loop should iterate for the number of employees and it should generate 5 radio buttons for each employee. The "Id" for each radio button should be in the format of: "radio_" + employee.employeeId + "index" where index will start from 5 and end at 1

Any idea on how to achieve that will be very helpful.

Comment: After importing the JSON, I think you need to start simplest part of the problem first. You can create an array of object that would contain both the id and the values. `[{ id: "radio_1_5", value: "5"}, ...]` as these seem to be the dynamic information amongst the set. Once the arrays are generated you can append them to their respective employee.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```html
<fieldset class="rating" *ngFor="let emp of employees">
    <input type="radio" id='radio_{{emp.employeeId}}_{{index}}' name="{{emp.group}}" value="{{index}}" *ngFor="let index of [5,4,3,2,1]"/>
</fieldset>
```